# How to convert rawstring to NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

Suppose I have the following code:

```
...
var data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil];

NSLog.trace(@"getdData:" + [data rawString]);
...
```

How do I convert the content of [data rawString] to a string (NSString)?

How do I convert the content of [data rawString] to an array (NSArray)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert the data into a string, have a look at the `– initWithBytes:length:encoding:` method of `NSString`.

With arrays, this is a bit more difficult, since there is no standard definition of what an array is. So it depends on the data format you are using. If it's JSON take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286087/best-json-library-to-use-when-developing-an-iphone-application).